# Build .deb from Qt project

Tags: qt

I have Qt project that want to create a .deb package. My project can be found [here](https://github.com/apinprastya/sultan)

I found 1 [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274311/make-a-debian-package-deb-from-a-qt-project) about it, it can compile but I need to activate some flag on pro file like `CONFIG+=USE_LIBUSB`, I don't know how to put those flag, because the tutorial is not fully explains.

Is there any tutorial how to build Qt project to .deb?

Comment: That exactly link I share above Abdul

Comment: Alternatively, use CMake with CPack